# jquery event when click on any checkbox of a specific form

Tags: jquery, forms

i have a form with lots of checkboxes.

the names and the number of checkboxes are created dynamically.

how can i get a jquery onClick event when i click on any of these checkboxes?

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_123">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_456">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_23">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_443">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_6764">
</form>
```

i wish to select them using the form's id, in this example all checkboxes that belong to form #myform.

**i ask this question because i don't wish to just add a class name to every checkbox and select by class name.**

my goal: an alert box "you just clicked the checkbox with name chk_{whatever the number is}"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an attribute selector:

```
$('#myform input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    alert("You just clicked checkbox with the name " + this.name)
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ULwK2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$('#myform').on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function() {
    alert('you just clicked the checkbox with name' + this.name);
});
```

Comment: Also note that you need to use event delegation with `.on()` since your `input` have been added dynamically to the DOM.

Comment: they are generated dynamically server side, i ll have this in mind if any client-side element addition happens :D

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it like follows:

```
$("#myform input:checkbox").change(function() {
    alert("you just clicked the checkbox with name "+ $(this).attr("name"));
});
```